# garchSim output not in 10 *2 format . I need the dates as the first column and Garch values as the 2nd

Tags: r

How do I convert the output of garchSim in 10*2 format

```
> c1 <- garchSpec(model = list(alpha = c(0.2, 0.4), beta = .2, omega =.5))
> c2 <- (garchSim(spec= c1,n=10))
> gfit.acc <- garchFit(~ garch(1,1), data = c2 , trace = FALSE,cond.disw t="snorm")
> c2
GMT
                 garch> c1 <- garchSpec(model = list(alpha = c(0.2, 0.4), beta = .2, omega =.5))
> c2 <- (garchSim(spec= c1,n=10))
> gfit.acc <- garchFit(~ garch(1,1), data = c2 , trace = FALSE,cond.dist="snorm")
> c2
GMT
                 garch
2014-12-26  0.31241878
2014-12-27 -0.02558373
2014-12-28 -0.33445052
2014-12-29  0.68646771
2014-12-30 -0.38295362
2014-12-31  2.24453598
2015-01-01  0.73116526
2015-01-02  0.98165356
2015-01-03  0.09430824
2015-01-04 -0.92170632

> colnames(c2) <- c("date","garch")
Error: length of 'colnames' not equal to array extent

2014-12-26  0.31241878
2014-12-27 -0.02558373
2014-12-28 -0.33445052
2014-12-29  0.68646771
2014-12-30 -0.38295362
2014-12-31  2.24453598
2015-01-01  0.73116526
2015-01-02  0.98165356
2015-01-03  0.09430824
2015-01-04 -0.92170632

> colnames(c2) <- c("date","garch")
Error: length of 'colnames' not equal to array extent
```

Comment: What's "10*2" format, and what does it have to do with the column names of `c2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify a package so the example is not yet complete, but I'm pretty sure that `c2`-object is a `zoo` or `xts`-class which have a matrix "core". If I'm correct, then you might need one of these to construct a dataframe result:

```
# c2.df <- as.data.frame( c2 ) # if there is an as.data.frame method
```

Or;

```
c2.df <- data.frame( date=as.POSIXct(index(c2)), garch= coredata(c2) )
```

Edit: There is an `as.data.frame` method but ti does not deliver a two column result so you would need this:

```
> cbind(date =index(x), as.data.frame(x, row.names=1:nrow(x)) )
         date           x
1  2003-01-06  0.94436731
2  2003-01-13 -1.39460234
3  2003-01-19 -0.60883152
4  2003-01-24 -0.97946327
5  2003-02-09 -0.08630589
6  2003-02-15 -0.69076969
7  2003-02-26 -0.78129047
8  2003-03-12 -1.72634717
9  2003-03-28  0.29721521
10 2003-04-02 -0.48914840
```

Comment: Tried this solution , I got the following error    
> c2.df <- data.frame( date=as.POSIXct(index(c2)), garch= oredata(c2) )
Error in as.POSIXct(index(c2)) : could not find function "index"

Comment: I am using a fGarch library

Comment: I tried something but the formula gave numeric values instead of dates as in c2                                                    as index cbind(date =index(c2), as.data.frame(c2, row.names=1:nrow(c2)) )
    date       garch
1      1 -0.65372862
2      2 -1.29360557
3      3 -0.50374128

Comment: I imported library xts and the code worked absolutely fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I gather you are using fGarch package.  `library(fGarch)` should have been included in the question to ensure that the code presented is self-contained.

`garchFit` from that package produces a `timeSeries` object and that can be made into a data frame like this:

```
> data.frame(date = as.Date(time(c2)), as.matrix(c2), row.names = NULL)
         date       garch
1  2014-12-26 -0.44551300
2  2014-12-27  0.62672096
3  2014-12-28 -0.64959826
4  2014-12-29 -0.87408593
5  2014-12-30 -0.19780425
6  2014-12-31 -0.49756846
7  2015-01-01  1.00466087
8  2015-01-02 -0.87103564
9  2015-01-03 -2.33823488
10 2015-01-04 -0.08257981
```

**Note:** We have converted the date column into `Date` class at the same time.  Omit the `as.Date` part if you want it as a POSIXct object.

Comment: Did not work out either? Got the following error Error in hasTsp(x) : invalid time series parameters specified

Comment: This does work with the data provided in the question. I have added the output.  Maybe there is some aspect of the actual problem that differs from what was shown in the question.

Comment: Sure, let me check it out. Thank you!

Comment: Start a fresh session, enter `library(fGarch)` and then enter the code in the question. Then enter the `data.frame...` line.  That should give the output I got.